# Plaid API Beneficiary Information

Tags: plaid

In plaid, is it possible to pull beneficiary information on investment accounts?

Looked at the accounts API documentation, and didn't see anything to do with beneficiary information. And didnt see any other relevant APIs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, this is not possible.